# Creating a dynamic array with given probabilities in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to create a dynamic array that returns me X values based on given probabilities. For instance:

[image: Check here the values and probabilities]

Imagine this is a gift box and you can open the box N times. What I want is to have N random results. For example, I want to get randomly 5 of these two rarities but based on their chances.

I have this following formula for now:

```
=index(A2:A3,randarray(5,1,1,rows(A2:A3),1). And this is the output I get:
```

[image: Check output]

The problem here is that I have a dynamic array with the 5 results BUT NOT BASED ON THE PROBABILITIES.

How can I add probabilities to the array?

Comment: Important: I do not want to drag to get N results! I want a dynamic array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could generate a random outcome with defined probabilities for the entries (Google Sheets solution, not sure about Excel):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  VLOOKUP(
    RANDARRAY(H1, 1),
    {
      {0; OFFSET(C2:C,,, COUNTA(C2:C) - 1)},
      OFFSET(A2:A,,, COUNTA(C2:C))
    },
    2
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems what I want! But I'm getting "Formula parse error" and I've done it like your example. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @AlexOrdóñez possibly due to different locale. Try changing `,` in functions to `;` and `,` in range construction (`{...}`) to `\ `. Like so: https://pastebin.com/raw/hKWJ6EHv

Comment: Thanks it worked on  google sheets. But I'm having this problem on excel. Do you have any clue about why on the offset is not taking properly the cells?: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QgxPDqD6_PQljWb4PY8gH2DM1mKhuQbf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AlexOrdóñez not sure, but I think there is no `ARRAYFORMULA` function in Excel, there is a different approach to write array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This whole subject of random selection was treated very thoroughly in Donald Knuth's series of books, The Art of Computer Programming, vol 2, "Semi-Numerical Algorithms".  In that book he presents an algorithm for selecting **exactly** X out of N items in a list using pseudo-random numbers.  What you may not have considered is that after you have chosen your first item the probability array has changed to (X-1)/(N-1) if your first outcome was "Normal" or X/(N-1) if your first outcome was "Rare".  This means you'll want to keep track of some running totals based on your prior outcomes to ensure your probabilities are dynamically updated with each pick.  You can do this with formulas, but I'm not certain how the back-reference will perform inside an array formula.  Microsoft's dynamic array documentation indicates that such internal array references are considered "circular" and are prohibited.

In any case, trying to extend this to 3+ outcomes is very problematic.  In order to implement that algorithm with 3 choices (X + Y + Z = N picks) you would need to break this up into one random number for an X or not X choice and then a second random number for a Y or not Y choice.  This becomes a recursive algorithm, beyond Excel's ability to cope in formulas.